# Why it seem that for Clour Run Default Service Account cannot be replaced?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-iam, django-storage

I am currently deploying a Django application to GCP Cloud Run.

I have replaced Cloud Run Default Service Account (....compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) with a custom one.

**But I get an error message:**

```
AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. ...
```

This bit is confusing me:

**<class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'>**

The error reported of the context of Django Storages which I use to store files.

- Is this message means the service account which is used by Cloud Run is still the default one (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set as Compute Engine)?
- Why not the Custom Service Account is used as an Identity for the Cloud Run?
- Why Cloud Run still checking the Default one I expected I replaced it with te Custome Service Account?

I am a bit new with the IAM, but if somebody could explian why it is happeing would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which dependency fail in your code? Do you try to create a signed URL?

Comment: The problem is your library is using ADC (application default credentials) which uses the Compute Engine metadata to fetch an access token. The metadata does not provide the service account private key required to sign data. This will require that you either directly use a service account JSON key file in Cloud Run (not recommended) or modify the library to use the IAM sign blob API. This link has an example in PHP: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob